# Using Document Provider extension without iCloud and DocumentPicker - non UI variant

Tags: ios, ios-extensions, document-provider

I recently found some articles and information on using Document Provider extension introduced in iOS 8 to share data between iOS apps.

But almost all the articles and tutorials made use of either iCloud or DocumentPicker.

I am basically looking to save some huge amount of data by creating a, say, Sample.txt file in say an app A. I was wondering from an app B, can I read the contents of Sample.txt file leveraging Document Provider extension?

I would ideally not like to use iCloud and also want a seamless transition from app A to app B on click of a button without any kind of document picker, controller, etc.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an App Group for this. Then you can access all files using `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"groupname"]`.
Of course, all apps must have the App Group entitlement added.